# Paging DataGrid Data using C#, Prev/Next don't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, paging

Okay, I have looked everywhere and tried almost every suggestion that I could find and NOTHING has worked so far. D: Here's my problem:

I have a `DataGrid` with `TemplateItems`that the user has enteres into two `TextBoxes` that populates with data after the click of a button. My button takes two dates that the user enteres into two `TextBoxes` and pulls all entries between those dates from a `DataBase`. The entries are then displayed in the `DataGrid`. What I need this `DataGrid` to do is allow paging with 10 rows per page. All I need are *Next* and *Prev* links to go through the pages that contain data. The links work but the data doesn't change (*Next* doesn't go to the next page, the data remains the same). I know for a fact that there are more than 10 entries for `Items` between certain dates so I know the data should change based on what page it's on. Also, the *Next* buttons seems to be infinite. Why? Someone, please help me.

Now for some reason, when I get the data from the database, it starts out by getting all entries but then it only stores 10 (which is the amount that I want the pages to display at a time). The data never shows the rest that there should be... Why?! D':

Comment: If you've answered your question, please post the answer here and accept it so that others will know it's resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one of my co-workers ended up helping me with this one. Okay! This is the final result of my paging `DataGrid`. All of this code allowed me to get the number of items pulled from the database, set the VirtualItemCount (which also sets the number of pages that display), and page through the data. Please note that AllDataSources is a separate class that just pulls the data from the database in a way that works with my grid's set-up and CamSizerData is the name of the `Table` that contains all the data and is used to get the Count.  If you have any other questions, please feel free to ask. :)

**DataGrid**

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgArchive" CssClass="data" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowCustomPaging="True" Visible="False" OnPageIndexChanged="dgArchive_PageIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="infoHeaderDG" ItemStyle-CssClass="line">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Line</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LineNumber" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LineNumber") %>'
                    runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="infoHeaderDG"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="line"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="infoHeaderDG" ItemStyle-CssClass="date">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Date</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="CreateDate" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CreateDate", "{0: MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'
                    runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="infoHeaderDG"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="date"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="infoHeaderDG" ItemStyle-CssClass="operator">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Operator</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Operator" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Operator") %>'
                    runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="infoHeaderDG"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="operator"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-CssClass="infoHeaderDG" ItemStyle-CssClass="product">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Product</HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Product" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProdNumber") %>' runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="infoHeaderDG"></HeaderStyle>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="product"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NumericPages" PageButtonCount="5" />
</asp:DataGrid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
    }

    protected void GetDateEntries_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgArchive.Visible = true;
        using (Entities ent = new Entities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QCConnString"].ToString()))
        {
            DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(Start.Text);
            DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(End.Text).AddDays(1);
            AllDataSources ds = new AllDataSources();
            CamsizerData cd = new CamsizerData();
            IEnumerable<CamsizerData> led = cd.GetBySelectedDates(ent, start, end);
            int counter = led.Count();
            dgArchive.VirtualItemCount = counter;

            dgArchive.DataSource = ds.populateArchive(ent, start, end);
            dgArchive.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void dgArchive_PageIndexChanged(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (source != null)
        {                
            dgArchive.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            Entities ent = new Entities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QCConnString"].ToString());
            DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(Start.Text);
            DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(End.Text).AddDays(1);
            AllDataSources ds = new AllDataSources();

            IEnumerable<object> recs = ds.populateArchive(ent, start, end);
            dgArchive.DataSource = recs.Skip(10 * e.NewPageIndex);
            dgArchive.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set New Page Index before you set datasource.

```
protected void dgArchive_PageIndexChanged(object source, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (source != null)
    {
        dgArchive.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        JSP_Extrusion_QCEntities ent = new JSP_Extrusion_QCEntities(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QCConnString"].ToString());
        DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(Start.Text);
        DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(End.Text).AddDays(1);
        AllDataSources ds = new AllDataSources();

        dgArchive.DataSource = ds.populateArchive(ent, start, end);
        dgArchive.DataBind();

    }
}
```

Also, why do you wire up your events on Page_Load? You don't need to do that if you do it on the markup.

These 3 lines:

```
    GetDateEntries.Click += new EventHandler(GetDateEntries_Click);
    dgArchive.VirtualItemCount = 200;
    dgArchive.PageIndexChanged += new DataGridPageChangedEventHandler(dgArchive_PageIndexChanged);
```

Should be declared in the markup. Here's how you register on PageIndexChanged for your grid from the markup.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgArchive" CssClass="data" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" 
PageSize="10" EnableViewState="true" AllowCustomPaging="true" Visible="false"
OnPageIndexChanged="dgArchive_PageIndexChanged"
>
```

[Here's an example from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagridpagechangedeventargs.aspx)

Comment: +1: what does `populateArchive` do? Does that query the database with the page range parameters or just filter it
?

Comment: @JamesJohnson dunno; I took it from his code. Looks like he's binding the `datagrid` to a Custom Object (AllDataSources) and `populateArchive` is just the method that returns the data.

Comment: Doesn't really matter if you set it on Page_Load or if you place it in the mark up. Still works either way. Page_Load just allows me to see what's what and what's where.

But I changed it to see if it made a difference and it didn't. I checked again and it seems as though when the data is populated, it only populates whatever the PageSize is. There are 28 entries between "dateA" and "dateB" but it only displays the first 10, ever. Those don't change with the *Next* button. :/

Comment: @SiSan I'm suspicious of this line on Page_Load `GetDateEntries_Click+=...`. Put a break point on `GetDateEntries_Click` and make sure is not firing on EVERY POST BACK. Because it appears that it is undoing whatever the PageIndexChanged event is doing.

Comment: populateArchive was my own code to populate the datagrid on the archive page.

And I iwll give it a try. It's really the same as if I were to just put "onclick=GetDateEntries" on the button. It's an ASP. I hope it's not effecting the PageIndexChanged...

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebind the grid each time you change the page. Here's an example that outlines what you need to do:

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanged="DataGrid1_PageIndexChange" ...>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void DataGrid1_PageIndexChange(object sender, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindDataGrid();
}

private void BindDataGrid()
{
    DataGrid1.DataSource = GetSomeData();
    DataGrid1.DataBind();

    int total = dt.Rows.Count;
    int pSize = grdJobs.PageSize;
    int pIndex = grdJobs.CurrentPageIndex;

    if (total < pSize) 
        pSize = total;

    int start = (pSize * pIndex) + 1;
    int end = (start + pSize) - 1;

    if (end > total) 
        end = total;

    lblTotalResults.Text = String.Format("Displaying {0}-{1} Of {2}", start, end, total);        
}
```

Comment: James, what's `dt` on the first `if` of BindDataGrid?

Comment: It was the `DataTable` bound to the grid, but I simplified the example and forgot to remove it. It's gone now.